# Save picture into specific row in database MySQL using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I have project from my lecture to make application that save biodata (Student ID, Name, Departement, etc.) into database. And also I want to save picture profile into database MySQL.

Here's the function to save all data (except picture):

```
public bool isSignUp (String nim, String nama, String jenisKelamin, String prodi, String angkatan, String pass, String verifPass )
    {
         if (nim==null || nama==null || jenisKelamin==null || prodi==null || angkatan==null
            || pass==null || verifPass==null)
        {
            return false;
        }
         else if(pass.Equals(verifPass)==false)
        {
            return false;
        }
         else
        {
            String query = "insert into dbmahasiswa VALUES (@NIM, @Nama, @JenisKelamin, @ProgramStudi, @Angkatan,  @Password)";
            try
            {
                connect.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connect);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NIM", nim);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nama", nama);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JenisKelamin", jenisKelamin);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgramStudi", prodi);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Angkatan", angkatan);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Warning");
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                connect.Close();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

How to add function to insert picture (that will be profile picture) in this method?

Comment: Take a look [at this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-save-images-in-mysql-database-using-C-Sharp/)

Comment: It is just another parameter adding a byte[]. But beware in your code you are not listing your columns and just listing the values which is completely dependent on the table structure. If someone modifies the order of the fields your code would fail if you are lucky, or would silently start to insert values in wrong columns.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(imageToSave.FileName);
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
        int fileSize = imageToSave.ContentLength;

        if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" ) /*you could add a check for what type of image you want to be allowed to save*/
        {
            Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            Byte[] bytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
         

    SqlParameter paramImageData = new SqlParameter()
    {
    ParameterName = "@ImageData",
    Value = bytes
    };
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```